# Visual Studio 2019 freezes when instantiating SOAP Webreference

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, web-reference

I am expierencing a strange problem with Visual Studio 2019. We ware using SOAP-webreferences in our projects. When I start a project in debug mode, the debugger freezes when the SOAP reference is instantiated. Waiting ~5 minutes helps but this problem strongly impaires the development. When I start the same App without the Visual Studio debugger, everything works fine. The bottom line is that I cannot use the debugger right now.

I already tried to set a breakpoint but nothing happens when the debugger freezes - even in the console.

Comment: Could you share some detailed reproduced steps with me for further check? If you try to instantiate SOAP web reference in a newly created project, will this issue appear? Besides, please kindly check following points. 1). Check and disable some(or all) installed extensions and test again. 2). Refer to this document Configure debugging options to improve debugging performance 3). Rename(or delete) `obj`, `bin`, and the hidden `.vs` folders under solution(project) folder 4). Try to repair and update VS from VS Installer.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? Please let us know any progress.

Comment: @JDW89, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue, if it helps you understand the issue, you could consider accepting it. And if not, please feel free to let us know your any concern. We are willing to help you further:)

Comment: Please let us know any progress.

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio 2019 freezes when instantiating SOAP Webreference

Please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage
Extensions** to check whether there is an extension causing that.

**2)** **reset all vs settings** under `Tools`-->`Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset all VS settings`

**3)**  [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

**then** run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder

**5)** try to use another port under Project Porperties-->Web-->Porject Url `https://localhost:<prot>/` like `https://localhost:44307/`

**6)** Or try run `devenv /safemode` on [Developer Command Prompt for VS2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to start a pure VS and then debug your project to test again.

**7)** If it does not work, you could create a new winform project in VS2019 and then migrate the old content into the new one to test whether the issue still persists. And if it succeeded, it is a better solution to avoid this issue.

**If** the error also happens on the new one, please [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update vs.

**Besides**, if these do not work, please share a small sample with us so that it will help us troubleshoot your issue more quickly.